# AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed

Tags: android

I'm unable to sort out the problem.I have two manifest tags in xml.
I am getting the Following error:

> **AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.**

I have searched for the error and got a solution that there are two manifest tag in code.If it is due to 2 manifest tag which should i comment?OR its due to something else?

Here is my androidmanifest.xml

```
<<<<<<< Original

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.github.andlyticsproject"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="217"
    android:versionName="2.2.3" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:name="AndlyticsApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Andlytics" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CommentsActivity"
            android:label="@string/comments" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChartActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AdmobActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name_admob" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AdmobAuthenticatorActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name_admob"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PreferenceActivity"
            android:label="@string/preferences" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationPreferenceActivity"
            android:label="@string/notifications" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AccountSpecificPreferenceActivity"
            android:label="@string/notifications" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ImportActivity"
            android:label="@string/statistics_import"
            tools:ignore="ExportedActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="application/zip"
                    android:pathPattern="andlytics\\.zip"
                    android:scheme="file" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- intent-filter android:priority="-100" -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data
                    android:mimeType="application/zip"
                    android:scheme="file" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ExportActivity"
            android:label="@string/statistics_export" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".sync.SyncAdapterService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:process=":andlytics" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/sync" />
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".admob.AdmobAccountAuthenticator"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".io.ExportService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name=".io.ImportService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.github.andlyticsproject.sync.ContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.github.andlyticsproject"
            android:exported="false" />
        <provider
            android:name="com.github.andlyticsproject.db.AndlyticsContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.github.andlyticsproject.db.AndlyticsContentProvider"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.github.andlyticsproject.sync.AlarmReceiver"
            android:exported="false"
            android:process=":remote" >
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
=======

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <application>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

>>>>>>> Added
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comment the second manifest tag. there should be only one manifest tag.

Comment: if this solves your issue can u mark this as answer, so that other who see this can know that this question is answered.

Answer (score 3):

Your version control system went and marked a conflict in the file (the `<<<<<<<` and `>>>>>>>` tags). You will have to fix the conflict before you can use the file. (The toolchain is complaining because the VCS tags are illegal XML syntax).

Comment: Actually i've comment all my xml and paste the orignal from backup project .Which neither have two manifest nor <<<<< and >>>>> these tags.
Thanks